# How to structure many questions intent in dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am making a chat bot to answer questions on a particular subject(example, physics). How would you structure all the possible questions as intent in dialogflow?

I am considering the following 2 methods,

**Methods:**

1. make each question as an unique intent.
2. group all the questions into one "asking questions" intent and use entity to identify the specific question being asked.

**Pros:**

1. Dialogflow can easily match users input to the specific questions using low confidence score threshold, and can give multiple training phrases per question.
2. Only need one "asking questions" intent, neater and maintaining it is easier.

**Cons:**

1. There will be tons of intents, and maintaining it might be a nightmare. Might also reach the max number of intents.
2. Detecting entity might be more strict and less robust.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to try Knowledge Base feature of DialogFlow.

You can give multiple web-page links from where it can gather all the questions, or you can manually prepare a list and upload it to DialogFlow.

That way you don't need to make it in separate intents, it will try to match it automatically.

Let me know if you have any confusion.

Comment: I am making bot where I need user to choose technology. Like angular , node. So if a user choose angular , angular intent would get trigger. I have many questions based on angular and node in FAQ knowledge base. How can I restrict questions to choose angular questions only if angular intent is triggered? node questions should not come from FAQ, unless user choose node intent. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61673969/how-to-connect-a-document-in-knowledge-base-to-a-particular-intent-in-dialog-flo

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an FAQ type chatbot. You can develop the chatbot in 2 ways:

1. Use Prebuilt Agents - Go to prebuilt agent and select and import FAQ and add your intents. 
   [image]
2. Use Knowledge Base approach - This is in Beta mode right now, but super easy to build.
   a. You need to enable Beta Features from the agent settings
   [image]
   b. Go to Knowledge Base on the left menu, create a new document and upload CSV file (Q and A). You can also provide a link for Q/A if you have.
   Check out the [documentation](https://dialogflow.com/docs/knowledge-connectors) for more details.
   [image]

Comment: i have tried to import FAQ agent (prebuilt), it created a new agent but it did not have any intent, only fallback and welcome intents. how to use that agent?

Comment: intents should be created for each question. user says phrases will be a different variation of the same question and response will be the answer.

Comment: that can be done by creating empty agent as well, FAQ agent does not provide any extra functionality?

Comment: Yes. I also didn't find it any useful. Had explored it sometime back. Not sure if there is any added functionality like Knowledge Base.

Answer (score 0):

Knowledge Base seems to be the best way, but it only supports English content